# Redirecting to phpmyadmin to secure subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, phpmyadmin

I have a **phpmyadmin** installed on my site.
And I already setup a virtual host for subdomain: **https://dbadmin.mydomain.tk** to access my phpmyadmin securely.

My problem is: I can still access my phpmyadmin through **http://mydomain.tk/phpmyadmin** request.

I want all request that pointing to phpmyadmin will be redirected to https://dbadmin.mydomain.tk

Please help.

Comment: You can use really nice `$_SERVER` global variable to redirect depending on the URL.

Comment: I checked on $_SERVER, and its related to PHP which I'm really not good at :P ... I was hoping to do more on .htaccess or in domain file (more on configuring apache redirect) ... but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the .htaccess (mod alias):

```
Redirect 301 /phpmyadmin https://dbadmin.mydomain.tk
```